# How do I put validations or assertions in choosing the particular file format?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, robotframework

I am using Robot Framework with Python and Selenium. I need to verify that files have the correct format: specifically that they are image files (e.g.: .jpg, .jpeg, etc).

How do I use validations or assertions to verify that the files contain one of a list of allowed suffixes? This is not as simple as verifying that the files contain a single suffix - I have to check that the file is one of the allowed types.

Answer (score 2):

```
def checkFileExtension():
 for file in os.listdir("/imagesDirectory"):
   if file.endswith(".gif",".jpg"):
      continue
   else 
     return false
 return true

assert(checkFileExtension() == true)
```

The syntax may be a little off but you get the idea. The function checks the entire directory. If any file/files are not gif/jpg then it returns false. Depending on your goal you may need to modify.